# OpenWRT is ignoring scheduled tasks?

Tags: cron, openwrt

My OpenWRT 10.03.1 Router (Linksys WRT160NL) is ignoring my crontab (set via System->Scheduled tasks). I want to reboot the router every night, since it tends to get flaky after some days. So I entered this in my tasks:

```
0 5 * * * reboot
```

I also tried

```
0 5 * * * root /sbin/reboot
```

but this was also ignored. Is there some kind of setting that I have to do, so that `cron` will be actually run? When I log into the router via `ssh`, and run `ps`, I don't see any `cron` process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default OpenWrt does not enable the `cron` service. To start it and enable automatic startup during subsequent reboots, you need to execute the following commands:

```
/etc/init.d/cron start
/etc/init.d/cron enable
```

The first command starts the `cron` service once, but does not change the startup configuration, so it will not be started automatically after a reboot. The second command changes the startup configuration (creates a symlink in `/etc/rc.d`) so that the `cron` service will be started during boot, but does not start it immediately.

Comment: This worked perfectly!

Comment: It seems odd to me that you would need to de this, yet in the Startup section of LUCI cron was/is listed as enabled with the rest of the items... (though it worked for me too)

Comment: This confirms it though: https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/cron#activating_cron